# WebView not loading all content inside ScrollView

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have some html content that I need to show inside a WebView, whose parent is a ScrollView. The content is basically some text with font, text size and font size customization. To avoid scroll problems, I set the WebView's height to wrap_content, so it doesn't have any scrolls.

When the content is too large, it gets cut off, so the WebView only displays a part of it, but if I scroll to the end of my view before the content is loaded, it loads completely.

I tried using a TextView insted of a WebView, but it ignores the customizations.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ...>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                ...

                <WebView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ... />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` instead.

Comment: That didn't solve it, unfortunately.